# Connect excel to ms-access front end database

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010

I have an access database split. It is part of an app working along with an excel add-in.

Question:

Within excel, should I address all query updates directly to the back-end version (in the shared network)?

Or should I connect to the front-end (local)?

As I understand splitting access prevents from data corruption in shared database (when users open same file). If I use a SQL command within excel and send it directly to the back-end, then I am using excel as the front-end (and that clears the issue, am I right?)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would connect directly to the Access database back-end part. Why involve the front-end?

*...As I understand splitting access prevents from data corruption in shared database (when users open same file). ...*

This is not quite correct. Splitting an Access database ...

> ...Splitting a shared database can help improve its performance and **reduce the chance** of database file corruption.

Source: [Split an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc?CorrelationId=b0bd40f7-1c0a-4467-b65f-65be8f41f06c&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&ocmsassetID=HA010342026) (Microsoft Office Website)

*...If I use a SQL command within excel and send it directly to the back-end, then I am using excel as the front-end (and that clears the issue, am I right?)*

Same as above. You are minimizing the risk when splitting an Access database into a front-end (form, queries, etc.) and back-end (data), but you are not eliminating the risk of data corruption.

Consider using a database system like Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle RDBMS, PostgreSQL or MySQL to further reduce the risks of data corruption.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Although I may have not address my question correctly. I know access is not the best tool. I am learning ms SQL server (personal interest) but my dept is excel-based (using access is a milestone!). Based on this I have to get the best out of it.
My question is:
Should I use VBA within excel to connect to the front-end version of the accs db? or 
because I am using excel as the front-end, should I just use a conn string directly to the back-end?

Comment: Why would you want to connect to the front-end? Connect directly to the back-end. That is where the data is.